# Do I need a transit visa to explore Seoul while in transit?

Tags: transit-visas, south-korea, icn, nepali-citizens

Hi I'm a Nepalese citizen traveling to Nepal from Japan and holding the japanese resident card have 72 hours layover in incheon airport Seoul via Korean Airlines. Do I need a visa to go out for the visit?

Answer (score 0):

There are conflicting answers on this website, as the rules have changed.

Currently, however, as stated by [Timatic](https://www.timaticweb.com/cgi-bin/tim_website_client.cgi?SpecData=1&VISA=&page=visa&NA=np&AR=jp&PASSTYPES=PASS&TR=KR&user=KLMB2C&subuser=KLMB2C):

> Visa required, **except** for passengers with a visa issued by Australia, Canada, New
>     Zealand or USA [...] holding confirmed onward tickets on flights departing within
>     30 days

and

> Visa required, **except** for Holders of onward tickets transiting
>   Seoul Incheon (ICN), participating in the Transit Tourism
>   Program for a max. transit time of 72 hours.
>   Leaving the transit area is permitted, provided staying in
>   Seoul, Incheon or Gyeonggi Province. Leaving the tour group is
>   not permitted.

As such, Japanese residency does **not** enable you to transit by yourself under the 30-day provision. In addition:

> Visa required, except for Holders of onward tickets transiting
>   Seoul Incheon (ICN), for a max. transit time of
>   24 hours.

In other words, you have two options:

1. Booking a Transit Tourism Program group tour
2. Obtaining a transit visa

**Because your transit time is more than 24 hours, the airline will deny you boarding without a Korean transit visa unless you can show you've booked a Transit Tourism Program group tour**

Comment: You transit through Korea on your way to the United States (excluding Guam and Saipan), Japan, Canada, Australia, and New Zealand and hold a valid visa (including re-entry permit, but excluding Japanese Group visa and electronic visa) issued by the aforementioned countries.
You transit through Korea on your way to a third country or the country of nationality via direct flight from the United States, Japan, Canada, Australia, and New Zealand to Korea after legally staying in these respective countries.
Condition of Permission is not true

Comment: @UmakantaPoudel No, that's the old rule and the website hasn't been updated.